# Slow Mysql query after inner joining 3 tables and adding indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, entity-attribute-value

I am finding my mysql query very slow, at 1 second according to my testing just from this query alone. I have tried adding indexes. But this doesnt seem to work well. i have attached my explain, tables and indexes. Im limited to only mysql 5.6 right now. Im not sure how else to make it faster. Any ideas?

```
SELECT symbol.name, symbol.code, tbl_company_data.id as dataid, symbol.id as companyid , tbl_company_data.company_size as size 
FROM symbol
INNER JOIN tbl_company_data ON symbol.id=tbl_company_data.company_symbol_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_eta metatbl ON metatbl.symbol_id=symbol.id 
INNER JOIN tbl_eta metatbl_0 ON metatbl_0.symbol_id=symbol.id 
INNER JOIN tbl_eta metatbl_1 ON metatbl_1.symbol_id=symbol.id
WHERE 1 AND ((metatbl_0.meta_key= 'word2' AND metatbl_0.meta_value!=''
     AND CAST(metatbl_0.meta_value AS DECIMAL) BETWEEN CAST(0 AS DECIMAL) AND CAST(1000 AS DECIMAL)) 
    AND (metatbl_1.meta_key= 'word1' AND metatbl_1.meta_value!='' 
    AND CAST(metatbl_1.meta_value AS DECIMAL) BETWEEN CAST(-0.0001 AS DECIMAL) AND CAST(2 AS DECIMAL))) 
GROUP BY companyid 
HAVING 1 
ORDER BY symbol.code DESC 
LIMIT 0, 1500
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_exchange_symbol` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `code` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=56287 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `tbl_company_data` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `company_symbol_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `company_size` double(30,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `company_symbol_id_2` (`company_symbol_id`),
 KEY `company_symbol_id` (`company_symbol_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=18361 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `tbl_eta` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `symbol_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `meta_key` text NOT NULL,
 `meta_value` longtext NOT NULL,
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `symbol_id` (`symbol_id`),
 KEY `TEST` (`symbol_id`,`meta_key`(255))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=470350 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Markdown Sample Data
tbl_eta

| id | symbol_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | word1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | word2 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | word1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | word2 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | word1 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | word2 | 25 |
| 7 | 4 | word1 | 10 |
| 8 | 4 | word2 | 8 |
| 9 | 5 | word1 | 3 |
| 10 | 5 | word2 | 22 |

symbol

| id | code | name | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | company1 | USA |
| 2 | AAB | company2 | USA |
| 3 | AAC | company3 | USA |
| 4 | AAD | company4 | USA |
| 5 | AAE | company5 | USA |
| 6 | AAF | company6 | USA |
| 7 | AAG | company7 | USA |
| 8 | AAH | company8 | USA |
| 9 | AAI | company9 | USA |
| 10 | AAJ | company10 | USA |

tbl_company_data

| id | company_symbol_id | company_size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100000 |
| 2 | 2 | 200000 |
| 3 | 3 | 50000000 |

Comment: Your graphic is hard to understand. Please [edit] your question to inser the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxx` for each table in your database. Indent the text four spaces and it will be formatted correctly.

Comment: Ok i have added the SHOW CREATE TABLE as well and formatted the input hopefully a bit better

Comment: @johnsmithabc They're still graphics, meaning we have to re-type everything if we want to setup a test platform somewhere like dbfiddle. We want **formatted text** here. Posting images of technical information like this is the fastest way I've seen to get your question downvoted.

Comment: oh ok will do, i am still new, let me do that for you

Comment: ok, thanks for the guidance, ive hopefully provided better sample data than just graphics, so will do this for any future questions!

Comment: 5.6? [Yikes!](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2022/05/04/whats-up-with-mysql/)

Comment: would use 8 make much of a difference. im just using a small cheap host for a small project.

Comment: Yes, 8.0 is a huge step forward.

Comment: 8.0 probably won't run this any faster than 5.6.

Answer (score 3):

When you have to `CAST()` a column value for use in a `WHERE` clause, it's no longer the same value as what was stored in any index you might have on the column, such that your index is worthless for this query. Worse, you can't know if a value in a given row will match the clause until after the cast, meaning you must run the code to do this conversion on **every row in the table**, even for values that will ultimately fail your test.

This is one of the reasons (among *several*) we try to avoid using Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) schema pattern as seen here in the `tbl_eta metatbl` table and friends: you can't really index them properly if you need to account for different types of value.

By contrast, if the values in your database were *already decimals*, and you have an index on the meta table covering `symbol_id`, `meta_key`, and `meta_value` all in the *same index* and in *this exact order*, you could use the index to jump straight to where the matching `0` would start for the `BETWEEN` comparisons, walk the index until you get to the end value of `1000`, and then stop there. You should build the index this way *even if there's always only one value for each `symbol_id` + `meta_key` combination,* because then the query can be completely covered from the index alone, without needing to look back to the table. It could potentially make your query run only a small fraction of the time.

Comment: Thanks Joel, lots to think about here. I will certainly go back to testing your ideas on design as well as use EAV and casting. Thanks for your help

Comment: ALSO FYI, the casting was to define limits between values. At two variables we are defining limits as some are anomalies so we define limits clearly to not pickup unrealistic values.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to optimize your code is by moving your filtering conditions (contained in the `WHERE` clause) before applying the join operations, like this:

```
SELECT 
    symbol.name, 
    symbol.code, 
    tbl_company_data.id as dataid, 
    symbol.id as companyid , 
    tbl_company_data.company_size as size 
FROM
    symbol 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_company_data ON symbol.id=tbl_company_data.company_symbol_id 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_eta metatbl ON metatbl.symbol_id=symbol.id 
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl_eta 
    WHERE  meta_key    = 'word2' 
      AND  meta_value != '' 
      AND  CAST(meta_value AS DECIMAL) BETWEEN CAST(0 AS DECIMAL) AND CAST(1000 AS DECIMAL)
    ) metatbl_0 ON metatbl_0.symbol_id=symbol.id 
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM   tbl_eta 
    WHERE  meta_key    = 'word3' 
      AND  meta_value != '' 
      AND  CAST(meta_value AS DECIMAL) BETWEEN CAST(-0.0001 AS DECIMAL) AND CAST(2 AS DECIMAL))) 
    ) metatbl_1 ON metatbl_1.symbol_id=symbol_id
GROUP BY 
    companyid 
HAVING 
    1 
ORDER BY 
    symbol.code DESC 
LIMIT 
    0, 1500
```

Note: I'm assuming your code is fully working and that you know what you're doing. This solution you see here is just an optimized query of the one you've written.

Comment: Actually, playing around with your code i got it working.  Will let you know the speed difference

Comment: big value from Joel's answer too, something to take into account when you get to play with indices and optimization

Comment: found another answer that seem to work much faster, i did the calculations  first which reduce the population THEN i joined back the information about the companies.

Answer (score 0):

EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) is an inefficient way to design a schema.  It becomes terribly inefficient when asking about a range on a numeric value stored in a `VARCHAR` (or `TEXT`), as seen in the `CAST()`.

These indexes *may* help with performance:

```
tbl_company_data:  INDEX(company_symbol_id,  id, company_size)
tbl_eta:  INDEX(symbol_id)
tbl_eta:  INDEX(meta_key, meta_value, symbol_id)
```

Since `INDEXes` cannot contain `TEXT` columns, I ask whether `meta_key` could be simply `VARCHAR(100)` (or something small like that).  As it stands, my second recommendation for `tbl_eta` will not work.

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Other notes:

( Don't use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  Switch to `DECIMAL(m,n)` if you want to round to a certain number of decimal places.

- Do switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.
- It seems like the 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY` for `tbl_exchange_symbol` would be `(code)` or `(code, country)`